# Bash Counter doesn't stop counting

Tags: bash

I have tried to make a simple bash Counter, but i dont understand why It never stops counting.

Sorry for asking this most probrably stupid question.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Number to count to: " max
number=0
while [ ! $number -gt $max ]
do
        echo $var
        ((var++))
done
```

I have tried to input numbers like 10 12 13 but it still doesn't stop counting.

Comment: You're comparing `number`, but you increment and print `var`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Benjamin W, i forgot to update my variabile name, Sorry for wasting your time.